# Add scopes to google login

Tags: javascript, web, oauth-2.0, oauth, google-signin

I have an issue here, before I was using the old Google Sign-in library: https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js, with this library I can just add scopes while initialising:

```
    gapi.client.init({
      'apiKey': 'YOUR_API_KEY',
      'clientId': 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
      'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly',
      'discoveryDocs': ['https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/drive/v3/rest']
  })
```

But now I want to switch to the new one Sign-In with Google: https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client, with this library I can find a way to add scopes to it. If someone has any idea how let me know please?